# Firebase select_content event : can't see item id in firebase analytics event console using flutter

Tags: android, flutter, firebase-analytics

I'm trying to use Firebase Analytics in my Android app using Flutter, In the documentation, it is recommended to use events defined in the SDK, I used **select_content** event type in that they provided  two properties **content type** and **item id**, using these two properties I'm logging the event but in the event dashboard I'm able to see content type statistics only but not item Id statistics as shown below image

```
     FirebaseAnalytics analytics = FirebaseAnalytics();
                 analytics.logSelectContent(
                     contentType: 'button',
                     itemId: '${item.label}',
                 );
```

```
dependencies: 
  firebase_analytics: ^8.3.4
```

[image: content type]

Is there some problem in my integration or is there no way to see the statistics based on item_id?

Comment: Did you find the solution for this? Having the same problem for an android app, select_content events are logged but no way to get the item IDs.

Comment: not yet, still having same issue

Comment: Facing same issue. Any solution?